# How to get most recent single item from many with ActiveRecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, activerecord

I'm having some issues with my code. This is probably due to some design fault. I've tried several things. Here are two.

Issue: I have a `1 (lending) - N (contracts)` relation. I'd like to call `lending.current_contract` which would return the last relevant contract.
Optimization is also an issue. I'd like to call `:lending, :include => :contracts` without having to use separate queries for contracts which are already in the contracts array containing all contracts.

Bad solution 1:

```
has_one :current_contract, :class_name => "Contract"
```

This doesn't work because every time I create, update or destroy it has to update the parent lending as well. Doing this I get a callback mess. For example when creating a lending, it also creates the first contract. For some reason going back and forth using callbacks for both the lending as its contract doesn't work.

Bad solution 2:

```
def current_contract
  return if contracts.relevant.empty?
  @current_contract = contracts.relevant.last
end
```

Sends a copy and not the reference. So `lending.current_contract.status = value` doesn't work.

Is there some design pattern which I should look at? And are there some examples? I've looked at some github projects but none of them had similar problems solved, therefore I think it is a design problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associations can generally take a `:conditions` hash, which can be handy. (And I'd forgotten this until I needed it about half an hour ago).

Would it help? Something like:

```
has_one :current_contract, :class_name => "Contract", :conditions => ...
```

Looking at [the book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) a bit more (page 364 to be exact):

```
has_one :current_contract, :class_name => "Contract", :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

...which will reference the most recently-created contract. You may, of course, have a more suitable column.

I wish I'd seen that earlier - I need to go and change some code now...

Answer (score 0):

By 'relevant', do you mean most recent?

```
class Lending < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contract
  attr_reader :current_contract

  def initialize
   @current_contract = Contract.New
  end
  ...
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :lending
  ...

  def before_delete
    # update lending to the most relevant contract
    # if this is the current_contract for parent lending
  end
end
```